# how to differentiate between the cases

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below two XML lines

```
 <para>
<content-style font-style="bold">abcdefg</content-style> This is out of content-style</para>
<para>
This is out of <content-style font-style="bold">abcdefg</content-style> content-style</para>
```

here in the first XML line, the `para` is having child as `content-style` and there is nothing between it, in in second XML there is some text(or there can be some more nodes even) between `para` and `content-style`, i just want to know how to differentiate these two cases using XSLT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <para>
        <content-style font-style="bold">abcdefg</content-style> This is out of content-style</para>
    <para> This is out of <content-style font-style="bold">abcdefg</content-style>
        content-style</para>
</root>
```

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <this_case><xsl:copy-of select="root/para[node()[1][name()='content-style']]"/></this_case>
            <other_case><xsl:copy-of select="root/para[node()[1][name()!='content-style']]"/></other_case>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the expression `root/para[node()[1][name()='content-style']]` says a `root` element with a child `para` whose first node has a name `content-style`. The second one is just the opposite.

Since hard returns are considered as text nodes, the use of `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` is necessary.

Comment: hi @Joel, thanks for the response, i just want to know, if i can use `apply-templates` directly, i.e. `<xsl:apply-templates sekect="root/para[node()[1][name()='content-style']]"/>`, thanks.